# jqGrid using XML DATA can't sort data in columns

Tags: jqgrid

I'm stuck in a problem with sorting data in my grid... It just doesn't sort when I click on the column (`totalprice` for example) to be sorted

I'll paste my code:

```js
// GRID Model
$("#grid-list").jqGrid({
    url:'grid.php',
    datatype: 'xml',
    mtype: 'GET',
    autowidth: true,
    xmlReader: { 
        root:"rows", 
        row:"row",
        page:"page", 
        total:"total", 
        records:"records",
        repeatitems:true,
        cell:"cell",
        id : "[id]"
    },
    colNames:['ID','Utente','Data Richiesta','Data Approvato', 'Data Ordine','Data Arrivo','Stato','Fondi','Urgente','Importo','Note'],
    colModel :[ 
      {name:'id', index:'id', width:50, align:'right'}, 
      {name:'userid', index:'userid', width:60}, 
      {name:'daterequested', index:'daterequested', width:150, align:'center', sorttype: 'date', formatter: 'date', 
      formatoptions: { newformat: 'd-M-Y' }, datefmt: 'd-M-Y'}, 
      {name:'dateapproved', index:'dateapproved', width:50, align:'center'},
      {name:'dateordered', index:'dateordered', width:50, align:'center'},
      {name:'datearrival', index:'datearrival', width:50, align:'center'}, 
      {name:'orderstatus', index:'orderstatus', width:70, align:'center'},
      {name:'funds', index:'funds', width:70, align:'center' },
      {name:'urgent', index:'urgent', width:65,align:'center'},
      {name:'totalprice', index:'totalprice', width:50,align:'center', sorttype: 'float'},
      {name:'comments', index:'comments', width:250}

    ],
    pager: '#pager-list', 
    rowNum:10,
    rowList:[10,20,30],
    sortname: 'id',
    sortorder: 'asc',
    viewrecords: true,
    gridview: true,
    caption: 'Ordini'
});

$("#grid-list").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager-list', { view: true, edit: false, add: false, del: false, search: true, refresh: true });
$("#grid-list").jqGrid('navButtonAdd','#pager-list',{
    caption:"Export", 
    onClickButton : function () { 
    exportExcel();
    }
});
```

Any suggestions of what I'm doing wrong??
Thanks for any kind of help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `datatype: 'xml'` it means that should implement *server side* sorting. If the dataset is not so large you can load all data at once from the grid and use `loadonce: true` option. In the case the later sorting (after first loading of data) will be implemented *locally* by jqGrid itself. The only thing which you need to do is to specify [sorttype](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acolmodel_options) property for columns which content should be interpreted not as strings. The most columns which you already use have the attribute already. All other columns will be sorted locally as strings.

Comment: what do you mean implement server side sorting?? In my testing code I loaded only 3 rows and it still doesn't work... Is there another "data type - data model transfer" that I can load from the server side and once loaded I don't have to manipulate them to be able to sort them out just with the Jqgrid?? thanks

Comment: @user2414235: your server code from `'grid.php'` should read *input parameters* which sent jqGrid: `page` - the requested page number, `rows` - the number of requested rows, `sidx` - by which column the data need be sorted and `sord` - sort direction. See [documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:first_grid#php_and_mysql_example_file). Instead of that you can only make initial sort of the data based on `sidx` and `sord` and return all the data. jqGrid will make *local* paging and later sorting without new requests to the server (to `'grid.php'`).

Comment: Oleg...I've been doing that already..// Get the requested page. By default grid sets this to 1. 
$page = $_GET['page']; 
 
// get how many rows we want to have into the grid - rowNum parameter in the grid 
$limit = $_GET['rows']; 
 
// get index row - i.e. user click to sort. At first time sortname parameter -
// after that the index from colModel 
$sidx = $_GET['sidx']; 
 
// sorting order - at first time sortorder 
$sord = $_GET['sord']; 
 
// if we not pass at first time index use the first column for the index or what you want
if(!$sidx) $sidx = 1;

Comment: @user2414235: the value of `$sidx = $_GET['sidx'];` is **not** an integer index. It's value from `index` or `name` property of `colModel`. Initial value are from `sortname` option which you use for jqGrid. The code `$sidx = 1` is wrong. Your server code have to return the data sorted by `$sidx`. So if you see unsorted (wrong sorted) data in jqGrid then your server code do sorting in a wrong way, but it should not work because `$sidx="id"`. The property `sorttype` in `colModel` will be used **only in case of client side sorting** (either `datatype: "local"` or if you use `loadonce: true`).

Comment: GREAT...the loadonce: true is what I needed! Thank you so much! I couldn't sort my grid using the columns in the client side. Now it works!